# creating a (proper) time counter in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, timer

How do you create a time counter in as3? Some simple search on google will point you to the AS3 class Timer that actually is a counter of events and **not a proper time** counting utility.

I have seen this http://blogs.adobe.com/pdehaan/2006/07/using_the_timer_class_in_actio.html and I am a little worried by the fact that it is official documentation that should work.

**Q:** Where exactly is the problem?

**A:** The Timer class executes operations in a stack of events and if you have a pretty heavy application I can bet the timer will distort your time if you use it to count seconds, milliseconds or whatever.

Answer (score 6):

If you're looking to accurately *measure* short intervals of time you just use the `getTimer()` function (`flash.utils.getTimer`), which returns the number of milliseconds elapsed since Flash player started. The prototypical simple StopWatch class is:

```
public class StopWatch {
    private var _mark:int;
    private var _started:Boolean = false;

    public function start():void { _
        mark = getTimer(); 
        _started = true;
    }

    public function get elapsed():int { 
        return _started ? getTimer() - _mark : 0; 
    }
}
```

[More Info:](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#getTimer%28%29)

Comment: This is definitely better than using the `Date` class

Comment: I have a little doubt since Date() relies on the system time but getTimer() relies on Flash runtime virtual machine. It should be tested but I think on heavy apps it may fall behind too.

Comment: @mugur On what do you base that? Either way it's asking the underlying operating system for the specific system time or system ticks (see for example http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GetTickCount)

Comment: Adobe says here http://goo.gl/acMmJ that the Date() function "is determined by the local time zone setting on the operating system that is running Flash Player" and here http://goo.gl/jkB2q for getTimer() "this method returns the number of milliseconds that have elapsed since the Flash runtime virtual machine started". Anyway the "ticking" system in Flash is not "ticking" properly if you overload your application ... I can bet on this.

Answer (score 2):

How do you override this?

We simply use the **Date** class also in a script that will properly count time.

1. Create a new AS3 document
2. add 3 textboxes named minText, secText, MilText and a button called start_btn
3. Add this code on the first frame:

var stt:int;// we use this variable to keep track of the starting time as a timestamp
var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(1); // this is our timer

```
var starttime:Date; // pretty obvious
var actualtime:Date; // pretty obvious

myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, stopWatch); // we start counting with this counter

start_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, startClock); // add a button listener to start the timer

function startClock(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    starttime = new Date(); // we get the moment of start
    stt = int(starttime.valueOf().toString()); // convert this into a timestamp
    myTimer.start(); // start the timer (actually counter)
}

function stopWatch(event:TimerEvent):void
{
    actualtime = new Date(); // we get this particular moment       
    var att:int = int(actualtime.valueOf().toString()); // we convert it to a timestamp

    // here is the magic
    var sec:int = (Math.floor((att-stt)/1000)%100)%60; // we compute an absolute difference in seconds
    var min:int = (Math.floor((att-stt)/1000)/60)%10; // we compute an absolute difference in minutes
    var ms:int = (att-stt)%1000; // we compute an absolute difference in milliseconds

    //we share the result on the screen
    minText.text = String(min);
    secText.text = String(sec);
    milText.text = String(ms);
}
```

Why do you need timestamps and not use the functions of the Date class?

Because if you want to count the difference between two events you would probably use this:

```
     endEvent.seconds - startEvent.seconds
```

Which is very wrong if your start event happens in the 57'th second and the end event happens in the 17'th second, you would get -40 seconds instead of 20 and so on.

Comment: `flash.utils.getTimer()` is more efficient, as per another answer

Comment: Thanks this is very useful for accurately counting time!